# Can we return List<P> instead of List<?>?

Tags: java, generics

Why does following code not throws exception?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public class MainRunner {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> s = new ArrayList<String>() {
        {
        add("a");
        add("1");
        add("1");
        }
    };
    // List<Integer> i = (List<Integer>) listConvertor(s, new Integer("1"));
    List<Integer> i = (List<Integer>) listConvertor(s, Integer.class);
    System.out.println(i);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static <T, P> List<?> listConvertor(List<T> inputList, P outputClass) {
    List<P> outputList = new ArrayList<P>(inputList.size());
    for (T t : inputList) {
        outputList.add((P) t); // shouldn't be classCastException here?
    }

    return outputList;

    }

}
```

I want to return `List<P>` instead of `List<?>` . But when I write `List<P>` , it means `List<Class<P>>` . i.e. in above case , it means `List<Class<Integer>>` , but I want `List<Integer>` as return.

I want below code: (so that i don't have to cast again at when method returns)

```
List<Integer> i =   listConvertor(s, Integer.class);
        System.out.println(i);
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        public static <T, P> List<P> listConvertor(List<T> inputList, P outputClass) {
        List<P> outputList = new ArrayList<P>(inputList.size());
        for (T t : inputList) {
            outputList.add((P) t); // shouldn't be classCastException here?
        }

        return outputList;

        }

    }
```

Comment: Why should it throw any?

Comment: your question title should ask to return `List<P>` instead of `List<T>`, no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the job with minimal fuss:

```
public static <T, P> List<P> listConvertor(List<T> inputList, Class<P> outputClass) {
    List<P> outputList = new ArrayList<P>(inputList.size());
    for (T t : inputList) {
        if( !outputClass.isInstance(t) )
            throw new ClassCastException("Faked CCException");
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        P p = (P) t;
        outputList.add(p);
    }

    return outputList;
}
```

- no cast on the caller side
- exception if inappropriate types are in the source list.

Comment: this doesn't solve incompatible types, though :) if the OP *really* wants to convert `String` to `Integer` then this doesn't help...

Comment: BTW: it also doesn't work when converting two different numeric types (ie. `Double` to `Integer`) it will only work for parent inheritance and not siblings, etc.

Comment: Strictly speaking: The question is about three things: Return type _not_ `List<?>`, no cast on caller side and why there is no ClassCastException in the marked place. Whether or not a real `String` to `Integer` conversion is expected is not clear. The method name might be an "artefact" since the TO did not specify much more than the exception.

Comment: Of course, but since this is clearly an example, the question is about having `List<a>` be converted to a working `List<b>`. And, even if you solution may work, in my opinion, does not solve the real problem behind the question. Note that I *didn't* downvote your answer too.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static <T, P> List<P> listConvertor(List<T> inputList, Class<P> outputClass) {
```

remember, you are passing a Class Object, not an Integer Object.

Comment: this won't work. It will still not throw an exception, but getting any item from the list will throw a `ClassCastException` *then*.

Answer (score 1):

No, of course it does not throw an exception. Generics are for compile time checks, not run-time. At run time, all your lists are `List<Object>` and the cast is made implicitly by the JVM.

---

**Edit** : in your code,

```
for (T t : inputList) {
  outputList.add((P) t); // shouldn't be classCastException here?
}
```

is actually compiled to

```
for (Object t : inputList) {
  outputList.add((Object) t); // shouldn't be classCastException here? -- no
}
```

---

For example, with your code, if you do `i.get(0).getClass()` you will *then* get a `ClassCastException` as the item cannot be converted from `String` to `Integer.class` (**note**: the same would apply however you do it as you cannot implicitly cast a `String` to an `Integer`. Period.)

If this is really what you want to do, cast `T` to `P` (for example, cast strings to a numeric value), then I suggest you use another pattern. For example :

```
static interface ClassConverter<F,T> {
    public T convert(F o);
}

static class StringToIntConverter implements ClassConverter<String,Integer> {
    public Integer convert(String o) {
        try {
            return Integer.parseInt(o);
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> s = new ArrayList<String>() {
        {
        add("a");
        add("1");
        add("1");
        }
    };
    // List<Integer> i = (List<Integer>) listConvertor(s, new Integer("1"));
    List<Integer> i = (List<Integer>) listConvertor(s, new StringToIntConverter());
    System.out.println(i);
    System.out.println(i.get(0).getClass().getName());
}

public static <T, P> List<P> listConvertor(List<T> inputList, ClassConverter<T, P> c) {
    List<P> outputList = new ArrayList<P>(inputList.size());
    for (T t : inputList) {
        outputList.add(c.convert(t)); // cast handled by the class method == safer
    }

    return outputList;
}
```

Than all you need to do is implement the `ClassConverter` interface to any types you wish to covert `T` to `P` and pass it to your `listConverter` method.

Comment: String and Integer classes are just example. I am doing more generic , any object to any object. anyway, thanks for this approach.

Comment: well, just implement the `ClassConverter` interface to the objects you wish to convert to. The `StringToIntConverter` was just an example too, BTW :)

Comment: you can't just convert any object to any object in a generic way... or at least you can call `toString()` and convert any object to `String` (or `Object`) but not any `T` to any `P` without any specialized converter

Comment: You can, if you are backed by 'Dozer' .. !

Comment: that wasn't mentioned in the question. And, frankly, for most use cases, Dozer is truly overkill, IMO. I have personally never found a situation where I needed to use such library. Are you *really* using Dozer *already*? If not, you probably don't need it.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainRunner {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> s = new ArrayList<String>() {
      {
        add("a");
        add("1");
        add("1");
      }
    };

    List<Integer> i = listConvertor(s, Integer.class);
    System.out.println(i);
  }

  public static <T, P> List<P> listConvertor(List<T> inputList, Class<P> outputClass) {
    List<P> outputList = new ArrayList<P>(inputList.size());
    for (T t : inputList) {
      outputList.add((P) t); // shouldn't be classCastException here?
    }

    return outputList;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Same as @A.H.'s answer, but much simplified using `Class.cast()`, and also got rid of the unnecessary `T`:

```
public static <P> List<P> listConvertor(List<?> inputList, Class<P> outputClass) {
    List<P> outputList = new ArrayList<P>(inputList.size());
    for (Object t : inputList) {
        P p = outputClass.cast(t);
        outputList.add(p);
    }

    return outputList;
}
```